# please help me to create a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have following 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dspartner](
[dspartnerid] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[priority] [int] NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hotels](
[hotelid] [int] PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[DSPartnerid] [bigint] NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [HotelSourceMap](
[hotelsourcemapid] [bigint] PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[dspartnerid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[hotelid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [dshotelid] bigint
)
```

situation is like this:

i want to table:dspartner contain details about datasource partner.
table:hotels contain details of hotels
table:HotelSourceMap contain record of hotels.hotelid, dsparnter.dspartnerid

new i want to update hotels table so that set hotels.dspartner = hotelsourcemap.dspartnerid
where
hotels.hotelid = hotelsourcemap.hotelid
and hotelsourcemap.dspartnerid = dspartner.dspartnerid (where dspartnerid's priorirty is high)

Note:-priority contain int value and the max int value will be considerd as max priority. if two dspartner have same priority then get any one of them

sql server 2005

Comment: What if there are two (or more) `dspartnerid`'s with equal high priorities? And what is a "high priority" - the data type is int, but that doesn't mean that higher numbers mean a higher rank - could be reverse for all we know.

Comment: priority contain int value and the max int value will be considerd as max priority. 
if two dspartner have same priority then get any one of them

Comment: And what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE HOTELS
   SET dspartners = (SELECT x.dspartnerid
                       FROM (SELECT hsm.dspartnerid,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hsm.hotelid 
                                                      ORDER BY p.priority, p.name DESC) AS rank
                               FROM HOTELSOURCEMAP hsm
                               JOIN DSPARTNER p ON p.dspartnerid = hsm.dspartnerid
                              WHERE hsm.hotelid = hotelid) x
                      WHERE x.rank = 1)
```

To make sure things are working properly, run:

```
SELECT x.dspartnerid
  FROM (SELECT hsm.dspartnerid,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hsm.hotelid 
                                 ORDER BY p.priority, p.name DESC) AS rank
          FROM HOTELSOURCEMAP hsm
          JOIN DSPARTNER p ON p.dspartnerid = hsm.dspartnerid
         WHERE hsm.hotelid = ?) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Replace the `?` with any hotelid of your choice.
It will only return one `dspartnerid` value, even if there were more than one `dspartnerid`'s with the same high priority.

Comment: getting this error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: and in query where we are joining Hotels.hotelid = Hotelsourcemap.hotelid   ?????

Comment: Doesn't make sense - did you forget the `WHERE x.rank = 1` ?

Comment: i think is should be like this, but still error:
UPDATE HOTELS
   SET dspartnerid = a.dspartnerid
from  (SELECT x.dspartnerid,hsm.hotelid
                       FROM (SELECT hsm.dspartnerid,hsm.hotelid
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hsm.hotelid 
                                                      ORDER BY p.priority, p.name DESC) AS rank
                               FROM HOTELSOURCEMAP hsm
                               JOIN DSPARTNER p ON p.dspartnerid = hsm.dspartnerid) x
                      WHERE x.rank = 1 ) AS a WHERE a.hotelid = hotels.hotelid

Comment: There is no `SET dspartnerid = a.dspartnerid FROM (SELECT...` - that's invalid syntax.

Comment: I understand you want to update the entire `HOTELS` table; I'm trying to demonstrate to you that the error you claim doesn't make any sense based on my answer based on the information you provided.  The correlation is what enables updating all `HOTEL` records.

Comment: i applied your answer and it updated all 121500 records of my tables because we dont have any were clouse in it.. i want to update only those record which have hotels.hotelid = hotelsourcemap.hotelid

Comment: Because of the correlation, `HOTEL` records that do not have entries in HOTELSOURCEMAP will have a NULL `dspartnerid`.  You can back that up by running: `SELECT h.hotelid FROM HOTELS h WHERE h.hotelid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT hsm.hotelid FROM HOTELSOURCEMAP hsm)` ...to list all the hotels that don't have `HOTELSOURCEMAP` records.

Comment: its done.. thanks lot:
WITH hs AS (
SELECT x.dspartnerid,x.hotelid
  FROM (SELECT hsm.dspartnerid,hsm.hotelid,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hsm.hotelid 
                                 ORDER BY p.priority DESC) AS rank
          FROM HOTELSOURCEMAP hsm
          JOIN DSPARTNER p ON p.dspartnerid = hsm.dspartnerid
         ) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
)

UPDATE hotels SET DSPartnerid =  hs.dspartnerid
                                   FROM hs where hs.hotelid = hotels.hotelid and hotels.dspartnerid is null